# What's the little plastic clip on the headset good for?

Tags: iphone, headphones

On my iPhone headset (the one that came with the device, as well as the in-ear buds) there's a little piece of plastic that slides on the cable to one earbud, and can clip onto the other cable.

- It's not large enough to accommodate the headset cable below the split, so it can't be used to somehow hold the cable in place when it's curled up.
- It's not tight enough to stay in place if I slide it nearer the earbud, so it can't be used to essentially move the point where the cable splits closer to the earbuds.
- It's not tight enough to really hold on to the other earbud cable. It takes nearly no effort at all to pull the cables apart.

**What in the world is it good for?!?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good for avoiding tangles when you're not using your earbuds, or when you are using them, from preventing you from tearing your earbuds. (When you're jogging or whatever.) That extra clip is the first thing to give when you pull them apart. If that wasn't there, the next thing to pull would be the splitter. Then you'd have half a pair of earbuds.

Comment: Does yous take more than "nearly no effort at all to pull the cables apart"? I find mine utterly useless to the point of me wanting to saw the damn thing off. Just wanted to collect opinions before I did something drastic.

Comment: For the record, I found mine today, and they take nearly no effort at all, but you know… physics 101, the “momentum” thing… one can only hope. Don’t “tear it apart”, I doubt there’s any gain from that and the loss could be the cost of a new pair (which, btw, will come with the clip again) ;)

Comment: That little plastic thingy is utterly useless, but I'll accept this as the best answer because it explains the *intended* purpose.

Answer (score 11):

I actually find it very useful to **clip around the buttons on my dress shirt**. Depending on the amount of slack I want, I can pin it around different buttons.

It creates enough slack in the lines/wires that go to the ears:

1. reduction in cord noise carrying up into ear-buds
2. the mic in the right wire stays away from your body (better pickup and less noise
3. if the earbuds fall out of your ear, they don’t drop all the way to the floor

It works perfectly (see yellow arrow in picture):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The usages you described are the correct ones. The Headphones ones are really lame, but it does its job on the Macbook’s power bricks. I made a pic for you:
[image: Clip]

I can’t find my iPhone earbuds, but the idea “is more or less the same”.

Answer (score 1):

The little clip holds the headphones, if gently, to your head notwithstanding some head movement. It has a more secure feel and holds the microphone closer to your throat for better sound on the other end. I do wish, however, that the clip held the opposing cord more firmly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, but I found another use just now, I clip that on the left earpod so it would be easier for me to pick next time…

Comment: What a great idea! I painted mine red & green (port & starboard) to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the little clip to hold the end of your earphone, when you wind it up.